# This Differential Equation should not have a unique solution, but it does, how?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given is the Question in which we are asked to show that a Unique solution exists for this ODE even though it does not satisfy the Uniqueness-Criteria.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y}+1; \quad y(0) = 0$$

**The Problem**

Considering real values, obviously, the solution to this ODE must be an increasing function which satisfies the initial conditions. But as $y(0)=0$ and  $y'(0)=1$ , $y(x)$ should give negative values $\forall x <0$ which causes a problem to the $y^{1/2}$ term of the ODE.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: It sounds like you're also asking whether not being Lipchihtz is sufficient for not having a unique solution and as this question shows, this is false. However Osgood's theorem gives sufficient conditions. See the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538490/classifying-non-unique-solutions-to-odes

Comment: @AlexR. I understand that the Lipchihtz condition here is not necessary for a unique solution to exist, however, my problem which involves $y$ being an increasing function and thereby causing negative values inside the square root remains.

Comment: What $x$ are you considering? I mean the specific domain. Perhaps you are following the convention that your problem is to be understood as $$\begin{cases}\frac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y), & x>x_{0} \\ y(x_{0})=y_{0} \\ y'(x_{0})=y'_{0}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @AndréArmatowski yes, there seems to be an implicit assumption that $x \geq 0$